# encode and decode Http request in Java

Tags: javascript, java, encoding, utf-8

I am sending a parameter from JS to my controller (Spring MVC V3). Turns out there is some encoding issue during the data transfer.
My JS Code is -

```
    var localUrl = "http://localhost:8080/TestFile/author.html?author="+encodeURI(author)
```

Value for the author variable is - Gilbert D’Mello

UTF-8 encoding for this is author variable is - Gilbert%20D%E2%80%99Mello

On retrieving this parameter in controller,
the String I receive is - Gilbert DÃ¢ÂÂMello

The code for parameter retreival is -

```
    java.net.URLDecoder.decode(((String[])request.getParameterMap().get("author"))[0], "UTF-8"));
```

I also tried using request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8") but nothing happens.

I am not able to properly encode/decode right quotation mark.
Kindly let me know where am I making the mistake.

Regards,

Vibhav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was that there was double encoding for this. One was using encodeURI(author) and other was browser's default encoding.